# Loaded SQL Point Data not displaying correctly in QGIS map

Tags: qgis

[image]

Having some issues getting my SQL data to display correctly in my QGIS map layout.  I am using Postgresql/Postgis, QGIS 2.4, Windows 7 (64bit OS).  I created a database with some point data that is supposed to outline the values collected at a specific geographical location in Colorado, but when I load the data, it is displayed as 1 single point in the middle of the Atlantic off the coast of Africa.  I will attach a screenshot of what I am seeing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8N1D.png)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance this appears to be a coordinate system issue - do the coordinate systems of your data (i.e. WGS84, State Plane, UTM, etc.) match the map space?

or possibly the x/y is reversed? but that prob wouldn't result in one point...

and if you're using the SQL "geography" data type keep in mind -

SQL Server uses the default SRID of 4326, which maps to the WGS 84 spatial reference system, when using methods on geography instances. If you use data from a spatial reference system other than WGS 84 (or SRID 4326), you will need to determine the specific SRID for your geography spatial data.

Comment: I suppose your points are really in degrees in range -90/+90 degrees N and -180/180 degrees E. In your map they are interpreted as meters around the Null Island http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the comment, when I created the database I used the following command: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'beacon_point', 'rsrp0_gem', 3395, 'POINT', 2);  this created the geometry column in my DB and I assigned 3395 as the SRID which is what I am using in my project.  @user30184 I don't understand your comment, can you elaborate pls.  Thanks

Comment: I mean that if system is using degrees as units like EPSG:4326 does, the coordinate range is between -90-+90 and -180-+180. If these coordinates are plotted without reprojecting them on top of map in EPSG:3857 like in your screen capture the whole world seems to fit inside a 180 by 360 meter sized box in the Atlantic ocean. This error is so common that the Null Island has been discovered. Are you sure that your data are in EPSG:3395 http://epsg.io/3395 is your projection? Could you show us the coordinates of some points?

Comment: I see, ok I have added a screen capture of what my DB looks like, this test data should show up in Colorado but as you have stated, there is probably a problem that is causing it to display in the null islands.  I checked the coordinates of the point I can see and it is 0, 0.  I tried swaping the coordinates around but I got an error from Postgis so I guess I did assign the longitude and latitude values correctly.

Comment: @user30184, I uploaded some screenshots to the original post, is there anything off from what you would expect?  Thanks

Comment: If you select projection EPSG:4326 and use -104.58 as longitude and 39.95 as latitude the point hits into Colorado. Notice that the values in columns x_lat and y_long are now in wrong order.

Comment: Ok, so I think I have it working now but what I did to get it working doesn't make much sense to me so here goes.  I set the map CRS to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG:3857) and my database data layer in QGIS is set to WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) and now my data displays in the correct location.  Any ideas why this setup would work?  I had changed the database geometry column to EPSG:4326, trying to get everything to default but when I set the map to EPSG:4326 my data displays approximately 1 mile off from where it is supposed to.  This is the only combination of settings that seems to work.